# NodeJS API deployement on AWS with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking for deploying my NodeJS API with AWS.

I tried to use Elastic Beanstalk but I always get this issue:

[Image of the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Rd2.png)

There is my package.json

```
  {
    "name": "",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
      "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
      "express": "^4.16.4",
      "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
      "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
      "mongoose": "^5.4.20",
      "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.2",
      "multer": "^1.4.1",
      "tslib": "^1.9.0"
    }
  }
```

And I also have a nodecommand.config into a folder named ".ebextensions"

```
    option_settings:
      aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
        NodeCommand: "npm start"
```

Also, is Elastic Beanstalk the best way to deploy my API ?

Thx for the answers !

Comment: Have you inspected the logs of EB from your instances?

Comment: @Marcin I went through every report logs and the only error I found was this one :
"[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [self-startup] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: staging application failed due to invalid zip file"
Actually I'm using a .RAR file but it shouldn't be an issue ? I'll try with a .ZIP right now

Comment: It can't be rar. Only zip, and in case of docker eb, can be just Dockerfile unzipped.

Comment: @Marcin, thx for the tips ! After reading logs after logs, I finally did it :)

First of all, I had to change my .RAR into a ZIP file.
Plus I was using the NodeJS v14 runing on Linux 2 of aws and my config file were not adapted to this version.

Comment: Glad to hear. I will make an answer, if you don't mind for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The primary issue was using `rar` for deployment packaged instead of `zip`. After fixing that, config files had to be adjusted to work with Amazon Liunx 2.